# How can pass list from controller to view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` and have this class in controller:

```
public class StudyClass
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string StudyName { get; set; }
        }
```

fill it that class with this code:

```
List<StudyClass> myList = new List<StudyClass>();
            foreach (var item in Query_Result)
            {
                StudyClass ClassStudy = new StudyClass();
                ClassStudy.id = int.Parse(item.Value);
                ClassStudy.StudyName = item.Text;
                myList.Add(ClassStudy);

            }
            ViewBag.List = myList;
```

now want to in view page access that list,write this code:

```
@foreach (var item in (List<String>)ViewBag.List)
            {
                <li>
                    @item
                </li>
            }
```

but get this error:

```
{"Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BookProject.Controllers.HomeController.StudyClass>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'"}
```

how can i solve that problem?thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @foreach (var item in (List<StudyClass>)ViewBag.List)
 {
     <li>
         @item.id  <!-- or item.StuduName -->
     </li>
 }
```